# PHP - Unbelievable Slow Image Processing

Tags: php

I have a function that returns base 64 image from URL. For a list of images (around 100 images - all thumbs), it takes almost 30 sec to complete. Is there anything I can do to speed up PHP image processing function (maybe some way to clear memory...) ?

```
<?php

// Get new dimensions

$url = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTnhDbj3HU9Sh4K71lOfJ9uMjESMTnYqLyJ7QLJf12asOj_o05N&s";;
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($url);
$maxWidth = 220;
$maxHeight = 220;

// Set a maximum height and width
$targetWidth = $maxWidth ? $maxWidth : $width_orig;
$targetHeight =  $maxHeight ? $maxHeight : $height_orig;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($targetWidth, $targetHeight);
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));

$white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($image_p, 0, 0, $white);

$dx = ($targetWidth - $width_orig) / 2;
$dy = ($targetHeight - $height_orig) / 2;

imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, $dx, $dy, 0, 0, $width_orig, $height_orig, $width_orig, $height_orig);

ob_start();
imagepng($image_p);
$data = ob_get_contents();
imagedestroy($image_p);
imagedestroy($image);
ob_end_clean();

if ($image_p !== false) {
    echo "data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($data);
};

?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: It depends upon your server performance , you have to increase the configuration of your server to process the request faster. Also there might be a chance to improve this by writing efficient code.

Comment: also for each image your fetching it over http using the slowest method.. twice

Comment: and why are you doing ob_*? that's a waste.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I need ob_* to get base 64 data of new image (with filling, aspect ratio...)

Comment: it increases memory, a better way would be to register a stream instead, your asking for improvements :/